# Locally deny login to users authenticated via LDAP

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, ldap, authentication

I have a RedHat Linux server that are is use for more than 1000 users

Users names are coming to the server via LDAP protocol, so login authentication is from the LDAP

My question: is it possible to block user login on the local machine, while users names come from LDAP?

Comment: You're using straight LDAP for auth? Not Kerberos?

Comment: yep I use LDAP  , and I see that from the /var/log/secure and LDAP files -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit logins via PAM settings:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-deny-allow-linux-user-group-login.html

Comment: may I need to restart the sshd service after config?

Comment: what is the diff between group name to user name - or maybe they are the same ? , because I want to block username

Comment: If you follow the suggestion to man pam_listfile, you'll see: apply=username is how to limit to a specific user...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DenyUsers` or if you want to deny a group `DenyGroups` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: can you advice how? or give example?

Comment: DenyUsers user01 in and after you edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config reload the ssh service

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps

This can be done per servers using PAM module.

root@test-login:~# vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

add below line

DenyUsers ldapuser1 ldapuser2 ldapuser3

DenyGroups ldapgroup1 ldapgroup2

Save the file and restart ssh services

root@test-login:~# service ssh restart

And try now

Comment: Yes, there are PAM modules that allow for this behavior, but sshd is not pam module.